# SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Array' cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP-Photo-Behavior found at https://github.com/dilab/CakePHP-Photo-Behavior and receiving the following error.

SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]

Query: INSERT INTO `photos` (`title`, `description`, `photo_dir`, `photo`, `school_id`, `user_id`, `is_slider`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('skjg', 'lkhg', '', Array, 1, 1, 1, '2013-04-12 01:14:09', '2013-04-12 01:14:09')

model:

```
var $actsAs = array('Photo'=>array(
                    'dir'=>array('upload_directory'),
                    'file_field'=>array('photo'),
                    'file_db_file'=>array('photo'),
                    'thumb'=>array(true),
                    'thumb_size'=>array(array("100x100"))
));
```

view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Photo', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Photo.title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Photo.description', array('type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => 3)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Photo.photo', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Photo.photo_dir', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Upload', true));?>
```

controller:

```
function admin_add_slider() {
    debug($this->params);

    if (!empty($this->data)) {

        //set the school id
        $session_school_id = $this->Session->read('Userinfo.currentSchoolid');
        $session_user_id = $this->Session->read('Userinfo.id');
        $this->data['Photo']['school_id'] = $session_school_id;
        $this->data['Photo']['user_id'] = $session_user_id;
        $this->data['Photo']['is_slider'] = 1;
        $this->Photo->create();
        if ($this->Photo->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Photo has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view_slider'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Photo could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }

}
```

debug:

```
data] => Array
    (
        [Photo] => Array
            (
                [title] => skjg
                [description] => lkhg
                [photo_dir] => 
                [photo] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => PLDMonth6Student_img_2.jpg
                        [type] => image/jpeg
                        [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBA8C.tmp
                        [error] => 0
                        [size] => 42085
                    )

            )

    )
```

Table:
`id`, `title`, `description`, `small`, `large`, `is_slider`, `created`, `modified`, `school_id`, `user_id`, `photo`, `photo_dir`

Thank you
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that Behaviour, but are you sure your set up shouldn't be:

```
var $actsAs = array('Photo'=>array(
    'dir'=>'upload_directory',
    'file_field'=>'photo',
    'file_db_file'=>'photo',
    'thumb'=>true,
    'thumb_size'=>array("100x100")
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **"dbColumn"** field in configuration array. It will only work if **"allowEmpty"** is **TRUE**. This field should be same as your database column name. In my case it's "image"

```
public $actsAs = array( 
'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
    'image' => array(
            'baseDir'       => '',
            'uploadDir'     => 'files/uploads/',
            'overwrite'     => true,
            'stopSave'      => true,
            'allowEmpty'    => true,
            'dbColumn' => 'image'                           
    )
  )
);
```